# Typescript: define all function parameters with a single interface

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to annotate / type all the function parameters in one single interface, even if the function expects these parameters separately?

This is my function

```
function f(param1, param2) { ...some functionality; }
```

This is how I want to type it (not exactly this, but something like this)

```
interface FparamsType {
  param1: string,
  param2: number,
}

type Ftype = (params: FparamsType) => void
```

Currently the only way i have found to make it work is either by collecting all parameters in a single object like this

```
function f({ param1, param2 }
```

OR by unfurling the interface when defining the function type, like this:

```
type Ftype = (param1: FparamsType['param1'], param2: FparamsType['param2']) => void
```

Answer (score 4):

A tuple can work, though it'll only hold the *values* of each argument, and not the argument names themselves (because different implementations of the interface could use any argument names that conform to the type).

```
type FparamsType = [string, number];
type Fn = (...args: FparamsType) => void;
const f: Fn = (param1, param2) => {
  // implementation here
  // param1 is automatically inferred as string
  // param2 is automatically inferred as number
}
```